Next.js 15 with Turbo: __webpack_require__ error in production
I’m working on a project using Next.js 15 with Turbo. When I run the app in development mode, everything works fine, including using map and other functionality.
However, when I build and start the app in production, I encounter the following error related to webpack_require:
Error: webpack_require is not defined
To troubleshoot, I tried setting global: false in next.config.js, but then I get another error stating that global is not defined.
For context:
I am using dynamic imports in my project.
This issue only appears in production, not in development mode.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue with Next.js 15 and Turbo in production? What is the correct way to handle this global configuration? Any insights or solutions would be appreciated!
Tried setting global: false in next.config.js: I expected this might resolve the webpack_require issue in production.
i am importing like:
const Map = dynamic(() => import('@/components/layout/map/here-map'), {
  ssr: false,
  loading: () => (
    <div className="w-full h-full flex items-center justify-center bg-gradient-to-r from-blue-500 to-purple-600">
      <div className="flex flex-col items-center gap-3">
        <div className="animate-spin rounded-full h-12 w-12 border-t-2 border-b-2 border-white" />
        <p className="text-lg text-white font-semibold">Loading 3D Map...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
})

My Map Component:
import React, { useEffect, useRef, forwardRef, useImperativeHandle } from 'react';
import H from '@here/maps-api-for-javascript';

interface MapProps {
    onMapReady?: (map: H.Map, platform: H.service.Platform) => void;
}

const Map = forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, MapProps>(({ onMapReady }, ref) => {
    const mapRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
    const map = useRef<H.Map | null>(null);
    const platform = useRef<H.service.Platform | null>(null);

    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => mapRef.current as any);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!map.current && mapRef.current) {
            platform.current = new H.service.Platform({ apikey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_HERE_API_KEY! });
            const defaultLayers = platform.current.createDefaultLayers();
            const newMap = new H.Map(
                mapRef.current!,
                (defaultLayers as any).vector.normal.map,
                {
                    zoom: 14,
                    center: { lat: 64.144, lng: -21.94 },
                }
            );

            new H.mapevents.Behavior(new H.mapevents.MapEvents(newMap));
            map.current = newMap;

            if (onMapReady) {
                onMapReady(newMap, platform.current);
            }
        }
    }, [onMapReady]);

    return (
        <div
            style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
            className="w-full h-full"
            ref={mapRef}
        />
    );
});

Map.displayName = "Map";

export default Map; // Ensure Map is the default export


Making the global: false  in next.config.ts:
import type { NextConfig } from "next";

const nextConfig: NextConfig = {
    webpack: (config) => {
        config.node = {
            global: false
        }
        return config;
    },
};

export default nextConfig;

and makeing dynamic import to normall Import like this:
import Map from '@/components/layout/map/here-map';

Also Download Global npm package
npm install global

